# Android adb pull restriction

Tags: android, adb, android-4.4-kitkat

In Android OS, how can I restrict the "adb pull" command so that users of my customized Android kitkat version cannot pull anything like files, apks, etc? Please note that the requirement is that a user cannot even pull files on a rooted device. I am open to an SeAndroid policy solution provided it is not just for /sdcard but for /data and /system folders also.

Comment: Can you remove the command from the OS image altogether?

Comment: While questionable in wisdom, this is a quite specific **development** goal, no reason to close it.

Comment: @Barend - right idea, but it's actually a daemon not a command (the command is PC-side).  One could attempt to prohibit adbd entirely, or else make a version where critical parts of the functionality to support "pull" are disabled.  However this will make development on that device a pain.  And it doesn't mean that other code on the device can't do comparable operations.